# Make button round in Launchscreen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to make an exact copy of the first screen of my app as a Launchscreen.
 The first screen contains a logo, a username textfield, password textfield and a login-button.

My launchscreen is completely identical except one thing: The Login-buttons corners aren't rounded.

I would like the button to be rounded, but Im not sure how I can accomplish this. layer.cornerRadius = 5 is the code but  I cant make classes, cant execute code, cant use runtime attributes on the launchscreen so it doesn't work.

I know I can make an image of the login-button or the entire first screen and use that, but I think a normal layout would be better because my app is used on Ipad and Iphone, so that I dont have to make many pictures so that every device has the correct proportions/layout on the launchscreen.

Is there another way to accomplish this? Workarounds? Or will I have to go the image route?

Comment: I suggest using an image with a [resizable area](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/deve65bd8d0d) so you only have to make one image for all devices.

Comment: Why can't you make classes nor add code?

Comment: @Roberto The Launchscreen is whats shown while the actual app is loading. Its basically just an image. So I cant change the button on the Launchscreen through layer.cornerRadius because the Code cannot be executed before the Launchscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In launchScreen you can display the snapshot of your first screen. Assuming that first screen login screen, which is fixed , you add an snapshot of your first screen in assets and render it using imageView in LaunchScreen.storyboard